# SQL query for displaying all columns in one table after looking at 2 columns in a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very new to SQL queries so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I have 2 tables with the column names in parenthesis:

- Client (clientID, username, password)
- Statements (statementID, clientID, charges)

I want to show all records from the Statements table but I'm currently given username. I want to use the username to get the clientID from the Client table so that I could use the clientID in the Statements table.

How would I query this?

Edit: below is my best attempt at querying this

```
SELECT *
FROM Statements
WHERE clientID IN
    SELECT clientID
    FROM Client
    WHERE username='user1'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the query that demonstrates your best attempt to resolve this yourself, and explain in what way that query isn't giving you the results you expect.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the query I used.

Answer (score 0):

The only issue with your current query is missing parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Statements 
WHERE clientID IN (
  SELECT clientID 
  FROM Client 
  WHERE username='user1'
);
```

Another approach would be to use *exists*, such as

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Statements s
 WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM CLIENT c
   WHERE c.clientID = s.clientID
     AND c.username='user1'
);
```